# SQL more than 100 'OR' conditions, and CASE/WHEN does not return the desired values

Tags: sql, plsql

I am writing a query which has a lot of `WHERE` conditions. I used the `SWITCH` case in the `where` clause but the result is not what I want.

I can't use `OR` because I have a lot of conditions which it will take a lot of time to check them all.

this is a small example :

```
select * from @tab t 
where hv = 
(case  
       when h1 = @h1 then 1 
       when h1 = @h1 and h2 = @h2 then 2    
       when .... then 3     
end)
```

this is the desired result:

```
 SELECT  *
    FROM    Tab  
    where (hv = 1 and h1 = @h1) 
    or    (hv = 2 and h1 = @h1 and h2 = @h2)
    or    (hv = 3 and ...
```

`CASE/WHEN` doesnot return the same result as `OR`, and if I change the order of conditions a different result is obtained.

I want the `CASE/WHEN` result to be the same as when using `OR` without having to check all conditions.

Comment: Just reading the title sounds like bad practise all over! could you give some background info as to what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: CASE output the first true case (so it depends on an order) - OR output ALL possible cases.

Comment: declare tab table(h1 int, h2 int, hv int)
insert into tab values(1,1,1)
insert into tab values(2,1,2)
insert into tab values(3,1,3)
insert into tab values(1,2,1)
insert into tab values(2,1,2)
insert into @tab values(1,2,3)
insert into tab values(1,2,2) try this using select * from tab t 
where hv = 
(case  
       when h1 = 1 then 1 
       when h1 = 1 and h2 = 2 then 2      
end)

Comment: The 2 ways you have shown as not equivalent. The `CASE` expression will never go beyond case `1`. It will either return 1 or NULL.

Comment: thanks @valex, yes I Know that and this is the problem if I have more complex condition, how to order the when cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare table `Conditions (hv, h1, h2)` with primary key (hv),
fill it with your values `(1, @h1, null), (2, @h1, @h2), ...`
and rewrite your query:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    Tab t,
        Conditions c 
WHERE   (t.hv = c.hv) and 
        (c.h1 is null or t.h1 = c.h1) and 
        (c.h2 is null or t.h2 = c.h2)
```